# LSTM input shape through json file

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I am working on the LSTM and after the pre-processing of data I get the data X in form of a list which contains the 3 lists of features and each list contains the sequence of 50 points in form of a list.

```
X = [list:100 [list:3 [list:50]]]
Y = [list:100]
```

since its a multivariate LSTM, I am not sure how to give all 3 sequences as an input to Keras-Lstm. Do I need to convert it in Pandas data frame?

```
model = models.Sequential()    
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(units=32,
                                               input_shape=(?,?,?)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do do the following to convert the lists into NumPy arrays:

```
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
```

Calling the following after this conversion:

```
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
```

should output: (100, 3, 50) and (100,), respectively. Finally, the `input_shape` of the LSTM layer can be (None, 50).

Answer (score 0):

LSTM Call arguments [Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM#call_arguments_2):

```
inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].
```

You would have to transform that list into a numpy array to work with Keras.

As per the shape of X you have provided, it should work in theory. However you do have to figure out what the 3 dimensions of your array actually contain.

- The 1st dimension should be your batch_size i.e. how many batches of data you have.
- The 2nd dimension is your timestep data.

> Ex: words in a sentence, "cat sat on dog" -> 'cat' is timestep 1, 'sat' is timestep 2 and 'on' is timestep 3 and so on.

- The 3rd dimension represent the features of your data of each timestep.. For our sentence earlier, we can vectorize each word